# In linq to EF can I create a dynamic query to search on a field specified by the user

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

We have some user defined data stored in a table with columns called "Date01", "Date02", "Text01", "Text02", "Number01", "Number02" etc. The user configures which columns are used and what the data stored in those columns means.

We now need to allow the user to search this data.

I could write something like this:

```
if (property.Name.StartsWith("Date") && search.Value is DateTime)
{
    switch (property.Name)
    {
        case "Date01":
            results = table.Where(clf => clf.Date01.HasValue && clf.Date01.Value.Date == ((DateTime)search.Value).Date);
            break;
        case "Date02":
            results = table.Where(clf => clf.Date02.HasValue && clf.Date02.Value.Date == ((DateTime)search.Value).Date);
            break;
        case "Date03":
            ....
    }
}
else if (property.Name.StartsWith("Text") && search.Value is string)
{
    switch (property.Name)
    {
        case "Text01":
            results = table.Where(clf => clf.Text01 == (string)search.Value);
            break;
        case "Text02":
            results = table.Where(clf => clf.Text02 == (string)search.Value);
            break;
        case "Text03":
            ....
    }
}
```

but this strikes me as potentially inefficient, difficult to maintain and difficult to expand.

"search" is a dictionary that's keyed on what the user calls the column and holds the value being searched for.

What I'd like to write is something like this:

```
results = table.Where(t => GetProperty(t, search.Term) == search.Value);
```

but I know this won't work.

I'd be prepared to keep the if/switch statement so I can do the appropriate equality test but I'd really like to avoid a big 20 item switch/if statement for each type.

Comment: You probably have to build an `Expression` or use dynamic Linq.

Comment: Could you use something like this: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library?

Comment: EF translates expressions to SQL. So you'll need to find a way to build expressions. There's an aptly named class ExpressionBuilder which should get you started.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks. I was failing to come up with the correct term to search for.

Comment: @CodeCaster Where is `ExpressionBuilder`?

Comment: @DavidG sorry, remembered incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this to build an expression:

```
public Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetMatchExpression<T>(
    string propertyName, 
    object propertyValue)
{
    var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    var propertyExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExp, propertyName);
    var method = propertyExp.Type.GetMethod("Equals", new[] { propertyExp.Type });
    var someValue = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);
    var methodExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(methodExpression, parameterExp);
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
results = table.Where(GetMatchExpression<Table>(search.Term, search.Value));
```

Comment: This should work for text properties, but unfortunately in OP code there is some custom logic for date comparison: `((DateTime)search.Value).Date`. So somewhere should be `if` that checks property type

Comment: @AleksAndreev - that's fine. I can work with this and get to where I want to be.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so talks of dynamic LINQ etc is skirting around the underlying issue of the database not being maintainable.

Please note, this is psuedo code taken off other implementations I've used that work.

In EF you can set up data inheritence by using Discriminator fields, so your table would become (please name them something different than Date and Text)...

ID
Date
Text
Discriminator

This Discriminator refers to the type of the object in code, and then gets defined in your DbContext, such as:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(builder);

     builder.Entity<YourTableName>()
           .HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator")
           .HasValue<YourObjectType>("YourObjectTypeName")
           .HasValue<YourObjectType2>("YourObjectType2Name")
}
```

Then, you use object inheritence in your models, such as:

```
public class YourTableName 
{
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
     public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class YourObjectType: YourTableName
{

}

public class YourObjectType2: YourTableName
{

}
```

And then, finally, your data retrieval solution can change pretty nicely, to (the same result is achieved for Text too, this is just an example of how easy the call is now, without dynamics):

```
public T GetByType<T>(DateTime date) where T:YourTableName 
{
     return table.OfType<T>().Where(a => a.Date.HasValue && a.Date.Value.Date == ((DateTime)search.Value).Date);
}
```

Nice and maintainable :)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the database schema to enable this. It would break far too many other things.

Comment: @ChrisF that's fair, I mentioned it on the off chance it was a new solution - just reading "Date01", "Date02" etc made me feel obliged to post this solution! ;)